# Django: Error while saving ManyToMany objects of ModelForm

Tags: django

I'm getting following error while saving the m2m field

```
Poll object needs to have a value for field "poll" before this many-to-many relationship can be used.
```

models.py

```
class Poll(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    created_on = models.DateField(auto_now=True)
    created_by = models.ManyToManyField(User)
    category = models.ManyToManyField("PollCategory")
```

forms.py

```
class PollForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Poll
        exclude = ('created_by', 'created_on', 'category')

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(PollForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['title'].error_messages = {'required': 'Please enter title'}
```

in views.py

```
if request.method== "POST":
        form = PollForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            #......code added
            poll=form.save(commit=False)
            poll.category = cat =request.POST['category']   #...manyTomany
            poll.created_by = request.user
            poll.save()
            form.save_m2m()
```

what wrong am i doing here ?

Comment: Instead of `poll_form.created_by = request.user.id` do this `poll_form.created_by = request.user` assign a user instance not the id of user.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to set `poll_form.category` manually: that's set by `save_m2m`.

(Also note `poll_form` is a misleading name: it's not a form, it's a Poll instance.)